# Vector as class member

Tags: c++, c++11

```cpp
class A
{
   private:
      std::vector<int>myvec;
   public:
      const std::vector<int> & getVec() const {return myvec;}
};
void main()
{
   A a;
   bool flag = getFlagVal();
   std::vector<int> myVec;
   if(flag)
      myVec = a.getVec(); 
   func1(myVec);
}
```

In the line `myVec= a.getVec()`, there is a copy of `vector` although it is returned by reference. If `flag` is not `true`, an empty vector will be passed.

Anyway to avoid this copy ?

Comment: what do you want to happen when `flag` is `false`? Do you need to call `func1` in that case with an empty vector?

Comment: if flag is not true, an empty vector will be passed

Comment: use a pointer std::vector<int> *myVec = &a.getVec()

Comment: @trenki please no pointers when not necessary

Comment: @trenki, yes ne way is to get the address and pass the pointer if flag is true and if false, pass nullptr. But i want to avoid using pointers as well

Comment: frankly its not obvious why you make a copy in the first place. You could `if (flag) func1(a.getVec()) else func1( std::vector<int>{});` Thought thats probably just due to your code being a simple example (which is good)

Comment: Every time you type `void main()`, a kitten dies somewhere.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: Well you've just doubled the kill.

Comment: @Bathsheba in the hopes of saving more kittens in the future :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
func1(flag ? a.getVec() : std::vector<int>());
```

is one way.

This will work if `func1` takes the vector by `const` reference, since both anonymous temporaries can bind to it.